# Is there quick setting “gap filling” adhesive?

Tags: glue

I have used “grab” adhesive in the past, but had problem as they take a long time to set and the object need to be hold in place until they set.

So is there a fast setting “gap filling” adhesive?   (A two part system when I put one part on each surface would be an option)

Comment: How big is the gap ?

Comment: @web, The gap is 2 or 3 mm at most

Comment: What is the material the adhesive needs to work with?

Comment: @John, sorry fixing some plastic vents into a UPVC sofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can depend on the size of the gap and the materials being joined.  Two options come to mind that differ extremely.

First there is '5 minute' epoxy.  Mix the two parts, hold for approx five minutes and its pretty set.

Second, for very small gaps, there is gap filling Cyanoacrylate glue.  Then to get it to set  fast you can use an accelerator that you spray on to it once its where you want.  I doubt this is what you are looking for though.  Its common to use this approach for filling voids in wood before finish sanding.